# make do while loop and for loop print out same thing as while loop?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, do-while

hello everyone i'm stuck on a problem and cant come up with the solution. I am using a while loop, do while loop and for. I know my first two while loops are correct, what I am trying to accomplish is have my do while loop and for statement print out the same exact thing as my 2nd while loop.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CountingLoops{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String message; // First message prompt
        String inputString; // For reading input.
        double numRows; // Number to be asked.
        double rowNumber = 1;

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the message you want to print? ");
        message = keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.println ("Enter how many times you want your message to be printed. Enter the value from 1-20:" );
        numRows = keyboard.nextDouble();

        while (numRows > 20 || numRows < 1){
            System.out.println("Number was not between 1-20. Try Again.");
            System.out.println("Enter how many times you want your message to be printed. Enter the value from 1-20: ");
            numRows = keyboard.nextDouble();
        }
        System.out.println("Output using while loop...");
        while (numRows > 0){
            System.out.println("Row " + rowNumber + " - " +  message);
            rowNumber++;
            numRows--;
        }
        System.out.println("Times in while loop:" + numRows);
        System.out.println("Output using do-while loop...");

        do  {
            System.out.println("Row " + rowNumber + " - " + message);
            numRows--;
            rowNumber++;
        } while (numRows > 0);

        System.out.println("Times in do-while loop..." + numRows);
        System.out.println("Output using for-loop:");

        for (numRows = 1; numRows < 20; numRows++){
            System.out.println("Row " + rowNumber + " - " + message);
            numRows--;
            rowNumber = keyboard.nextDouble();
        }
    }
}
```

Enter the message you want to print?

hello

Enter how many times you want your message to be printed. Enter the value from 1-20:

5

Output using while loop...

Row 1.0 - hello

Row 2.0 - hello

Row 3.0 - hello

Row 4.0 - hello

Row 5.0 - hello

Times in while loop:0.0

Output using do-while loop...

Row 6.0 - hello

Times in do-while loop...-1.0

Output using for-loop:

Row 7.0 - hello

(This is what prints when I run my program, what I am looking for to print is this below)

Output using while loop...

Row 1.0 - hello

Row 2.0 - hello

Row 3.0 - hello

Row 4.0 - hello

Row 5.0 - hello

Times in while loop:5

Output using do-while loop...

Row 1.0 - hello

Row 2.0 - hello

Row 3.0 - hello

Row 4.0 - hello

Row 5.0 - hello

Times in do while loop: 5

Output using for-loop...

Row 1.0 - hello

Row 2.0 - hello

Row 3.0 - hello

Row 4.0 - hello

Row 5.0 - hello

Times in for loop: 5

Comment: Have you tried resetting your variables between the loops?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are decrementing numRows in your loops, but never setting it back to its original value.

```
        String message; // First message prompt
        String inputString; // For reading input.
        double numRows; // Number to be asked.
        double rowNumber = 0;

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter the message you want to print? ");
        message = keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter how many times you want your message to beprinted.Enter the value from 1-20:");
        numRows = keyboard.nextDouble();

        double currentRow = numRows;
        while (currentRow > 0) {
            System.out.println("[WHILE] Row " + rowNumber + " - " + message);
            rowNumber++;
            currentRow--;
        }

        System.out.println("Times in while loop:" + rowNumber);
        System.out.println("Output using do-while loop...");
        currentRow = numRows;
        rowNumber = 1;

        do {
            System.out.println("[DO WHILE] Row " + rowNumber + " - " + message);
            currentRow--;
            rowNumber++;
        } while (currentRow > 0);

        System.out.println("Times in do-while loop..." + numRows);
        System.out.println("Output using for-loop:");
        currentRow = numRows;
        rowNumber = 1;

        for (double i = currentRow; currentRow > 0; currentRow--) {
            System.out.println("[FOR LOOP] Row " + rowNumber + " - " + message);
        }
```

Comment: Thank you so much I see what I was doing wrong. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

You're decrementing numRows in your first loop (the while loop). You need to preserve the value of numRows for each of your loops to use. In addition, reset rowNumber to 1 for each loop.